# Product of functions and a product of their integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that if $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are nonnegative continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$, then there exists some $x  \in [0,1]$ such that $$f_1(x)f_2(x) \cdots f_n(x) \leq \int_0^1f_1 \int_0^1f_2 \cdots \int_0^1 f_n$$

This was my old math department's problem-of-the-month recently, and I haven't been able to figure it out. I can't get anywhere with the simpler theorems from analysis, like the mean-value-theorems. I would certainly like to solve it for myself, so hints are most appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Can you do the case where $ n = 1 $? For general case, let $ R(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n )  = f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2) \cdots f_n(x_n) $. Then $ \int_I R $ is the right side, where $ I = [0,1]^n $.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I worked on it some today. If the problem asked for any $\vec{x} \in I$ that satisfied this inequality, then it's pretty easy. But to answer the problem as stated, we would have to find an $\vec{x}$ on the "diagonal" of $I$, right? I can find the $\vec{x}$ that gives a minimal value $m$ of $R$ on the diagonal, but now I'm stuck on getting a relationship between $m$ and $\int_I R$

Comment: @upvoters Why the up vote?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that this doesn't happen. Then, raise both sides to the 1/n, and use the generalized Holder inequality to reach a contradiction.